# Returning values from class A to class B and then to Main class?

Tags: java, class, oop

I am programming a simple character creation program to study classes and Java programming.

The code is work in progress and not runnable because I don't know how to make it work.

My problem is that I don't know how to properly return details/info/values from another class to another class and then to the main class.

What I am trying to solve is how to get the information stored in `weapon.java` and `characteristic.java` , so that I can use them in `player.java`. So lets say a user inputs 1 for warrior. Then I need to get the information for Weapon and Characteristics from their own classes, and return this information for `SetClass` Method in `Player.java`.

In short something like:
If user input = 1 => classType is Warrior => weaponType is Sword 
Anyways

Here is my code so far:

**The main program:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class characterCreationProgam {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main1(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the super simple character creator ");
            System.out.println("Choose class: 1: Warrior 2: Wizard 3: Rogue 4: Healer ");
            int class = input.nextInt();

            // creating new OOP
            Player newCharacter = new Player(class);

            newCharacter.setClass(class);

            System.out.println("New character has been made: ");
            newCharacter.printPlayer();

            System.out.println("Print character stats? 1: Yes 2: No ");
            int answer = input.nextInt();
            if (answer == 1) {
                newCharacter.printClass();
            } else if (answer == 2) {
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("Print weapon stats? 1: Yes 2: No ");
            int answer2 = input.nextInt();
            if (answer2 == 1) {
                newCharacter.printWeapon();
            } else if (answer2 == 2) {
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("Shutting down the program.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error! Program closing.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.Java class**

```
public class Player {

    private int class;
    private String sex;
    private int age;
    private int weapon;

    public Player(int class) {
        this.class = class;
        this.sex = "";
        this.age = 0;
        this.weapon = 0;
    }

    // Method for setting the class
    public void setClass(int class) {

        if (class == 1) { // Warrior
            // something here to return proper character class and weapon
            // from their own class files
            this.sex = "Male";
            this.age = 45;

        } else if (class == 2) { // Wizard
            // something here to return proper character class and weapon
            // from their own class files
            this.sex = "Female";
            this.age = 30;

        } else if (class == 3) { // Rogue
            // something here to return proper character class and weapon
            // from their own class files
            this.sex = "Female";
            this.age = 25;

        } else if (class == 4) { // healer
            // something here to return proper character class and weapon
            // from their own class files
            this.sukupuoli = "Male";
            this.age = 21;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Unkown class selection. ");
        }
    }

    // Method to return/print character info
    public void printPlayer() {
        System.out.println("class: " + this.class + "\nGender: "
            + this.sex + "\nAge: " + this.age + "\nWeapon: "
            + this.weapon);
    }

    // Method to return/print class info
    public void printClass() {
        // Something here to return classInfo from CharacterClass.Java
    }

    // Method to return/print weapon info
    public void printWeapon() {
        // Something here to return weaponInfo from Weapon.Java
    }
}
```

**Characterstics.Java class**

```
public class Class {

    private String className;
    private int classLevel;
    private String specialSkills;

    public Class(String name, int level, String skills) {
        this.className = name;
        this.classLevel = level;
        this.specialSkills = skills;
    }

    public void classType() {

        if () { // Don't know what to put in here
            this.className = "Warrior";
            this.classLevel = 90;
            this.specialSkills = "Damage reduction";
            // Something to set correct weapon to this classType from
            // weapon.java

        } else if () { // Don't know what to put in here
            this.className = "Wizard";
            this.classLevel = 75;
            this.specialSkills = "Magic ";
            // Something to set correct weapon to this classType from
            // weapon.java

        } else if () { // Don't know what to put in here
            this.className = "Rogue";
            this.classLevel = 55;
            this.specialSkills = "Dodge";
            // Something to set correct weapon to this classType from
            // weapon.java

        } else if () { // Don't know what to put in here
            this.className = "Healer";
            this.classLevel = 69;
            this.specialSkills = "Healing";
            // Something to set correct weapon to this classType from
            // weapon.java
        }
    }

    // Method to return characters details.
    public void characterInfo() {
        System.out.println("\nClass: " + this.className + "\nLevel: "
            + this.classLevel + "\nSkills: " + this.specialSkills);
    }
}
```

and finally...
**Weapon.Java class**

```
public class Weapon {

    // Luokan
    private int damage;
    private String type;
    private String bonus;

    public Weapon() {
        this.damage = 0;
        this.type = "";
        this.bonus = "";
    }

    public void weaponType() {

        if () { // Don't know what to put in here, class is warrior
            this.type = "Sword";
            this.damage = 75;
            this.bonus = "Armor penetration";

        } else if () { // Don't know what to put in here, class is wizard
            this.type = "Staff";
            this.damage = 35;
            this.bonus = "Spell casting";

        } else if () { // Don't know what to put in here, class is rogue
            this.type = "Daggers";
            this.damage = 55;
            this.bonus = "Poisoning enemies";

        } else if () { // Don't know what to put in here, class is healer
            this.type = "Hammer";
            this.damage = 85;
            this.bonus = "Stunning enemies";
        }
    }

    // Method to print weapon details.
    public void weaponInfo() {
        System.out.println("Weapon type: " + this.type + "\nDamage: "
            + this.damage + "\nBonus: " + this.bonus);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't really understand the question. Despite that, I'm having trouble accepting your code as OOP and you can't use class as a variable name since it's already bounded to the language

Comment: And also, you need to work on your indentation please

Comment: What I am trying to solve is how to get the information stored in weapon.java and characteristic,java , so that I can use them in player.java. So lets say a user inputs 1 for warrior. Then I need to get the information for Weapon and Characteristics from their own classes, and return this information for SetClass Method in Player.Java

Comment: What I am trying to solve is how to get the information stored in weapon.java and characteristic,java , so that I can use them in player.java. So lets say a user inputs 1 for warrior. Then I need to get the information for Weapon and Characteristics from their own classes, and return this information for SetClass Method in Player.Java. In short

Comment: I don't think this question is really suited for here, there are simple ways of making it "work" but that wouldn't mean it's good code. I wouldn't mind to try explaining how to improve your code, but I think it isn't suited for here so If you want contact me over peddavid96@outlook.com

Answer (score 2):

You can always get Atributes from other classes by writing [Getters](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html).

Also, as Pedro David already said you can't use "class" for naming classes and variables as it is a [Reserved Word](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

This being said, here is my solution for your problem (It's far from perfect but hopefully you'll see how to easily share information between classes)

```
import java.util.*;

public class CharacterCreationProgam {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            System.out.println("Welcome to the super simple character creator ");
            System.out.println("Choose class: 1: Warrior 2: Wizard 3: Rogue 4: Healer ");
            int race = input.nextInt();

            //creating new Player-Object:
            Player player = new Player(race);

            System.out.println("New character has been made: ");

            //Character stats:
            System.out.println("Print character stats? 1: Yes 2: No ");
            int answer = input.nextInt();
            if (answer == 1) {
                System.out.println("Race: " + player.getRace().getraceName() + 
                        "\nGender: " + player.getSex() + 
                        "\nAge: " + player.getAge());
            }

            //Weapon stats:
            System.out.println("Print weapon stats? 1: Yes 2: No ");
            answer = input.nextInt();
            if (answer == 1) {
                Weapon playerWeapon = player.getWeapon();
                System.out.println("Weapon Type: " + playerWeapon.getType() + 
                        "\nDamage: " + playerWeapon.getDamage() + 
                        "\nBonus: " + playerWeapon.getBonus());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }finally{
            input.close();
        }


    }

}
```

Here is my go at a Player.java:

```
public class Player {

    private Race playerRace;
    private String sex;
    private int age;
    private Weapon weapon;


    public Player(int race) throws Exception{
        setRace(race);
        setAtributes();
        setWeapon();
    }

    private void setRace(int race) throws Exception{
        this.playerRace = new Race(race);

    }

    private void setAtributes() throws Exception{

        switch (playerRace.getraceName()) {
            case "Warrior":
                this.sex = "Male";
                this.age = 45;
                break;

            case "Wizard":
                this.sex = "Female";
                this.age = 30;
                break;

            case "Rogue":
                this.sex = "Female";
                this.age = 25;
                break;

            case "Healer":
                this.sex = "Male";
                this.age = 21;
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    private void setWeapon() throws Exception{
        weapon = new Weapon(playerRace);
    }

    public String getSex(){
        return sex;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public Weapon getWeapon(){
        return weapon;
    }

    public Race getRace(){
        return playerRace;
    }

}
```

My Race.java:

```
public class Race {

    private String raceName; //Enum would be BP
    private int raceLevel;
    private String specialSkill; //Another Class for the skills would be Nice in the long run

    public Race(int race) throws Exception{
        setRace(race);
    }


    private void setRace(int race) throws Exception{

        switch (race) {
            case 1: //Warrior
                this.raceName = "Warrior";
                this.raceLevel = 90;
                this.specialSkill = "Damage reduction";
                break;

            case 2: //Wizard
                this.raceName = "Wizard";
                this.raceLevel = 75;
                this.specialSkill = "Magic";
                break;

            case 3: //Rogue
                this.raceName = "Rogue";
                this.raceLevel = 55;
                this.specialSkill= "Dodge";
                break;

            case 4: //Healer
                this.raceName = "Healer";
                this.raceLevel = 69;
                this.specialSkill= "Healing";
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception(); //you should find a fitting Exception for this
        }
    }

    public String getraceName(){
        return this.raceName;
    }

    public int getraceLevel(){
        return this.raceLevel;
    }

    public String specialSkill(){
        return this.specialSkill;
    }

}
```

And the Weapon.java:

```
public class Weapon {

    private int damage;
    private String type;
    private String bonus;

    public Weapon(Race race) throws Exception{
        setWeapon(race);
    }

    private void setWeapon(Race race) throws Exception{
        switch (race.getraceName()) {
            case "Warrior":
                this.type = "Sword";
                this.damage = 75;
                this.bonus = "Armor penetration";
                break;

            case "Wizard":
                this.type = "Staff";
                this.damage = 35;
                this.bonus = "Spell casting";
                break;

            case "Rogue":
                this.type = "Daggers";
                this.damage = 55;
                this.bonus = "Poisoning enemies";
                break;

            case "Healer":
                this.type = "Hammer";
                this.damage = 85;
                this.bonus = "Stunning enemies";
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }


    public int getDamage(){
        return damage;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public String getBonus(){
        return bonus;
    }

}
```

So as you can see I use Switch statements with the getters from the objects. I hope this is somewhat helpful, if you have any questions please ask ;)

Comment: This is an hard upvote to give. You told him how to do it and it works. That said this is far from good OOP design. Thanks for remembering me about the keyword "Reserved" though :)

Comment: I agree, it's not really great. I tried to stay close to what he wrote rather than writing my own version, and I'm no expert myself ;)

Comment: But I hope it shows how easy it is to write a getter method, which was, I think, his original question

Comment: Your answer was probably the best someone could give to this question.

Comment: Thank you, I will use this as a reference as I try to figure out how to solve it.